# Nested Dictionary to single or none

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like below:

```py
{'head1': {'args': 'arg1',
'sch': ('0-59', '05-09', 12, '03', '*')},
'head2': {'args': 'arg2',
'sch': ('0-59', '05-09', 12, '03', '*')}
```

I want the output as:

```
head1:
 args: args1
 sche: 0-59 05-09 12 03 * 
head2:
 args: args2
 sche: 0-59 05-09 12 03 *
```

I wanted to reduce or remove the dictionary completely. please suggest an idea on how to approach this problem, open to any ideas...

I tried something below, almost near to what am looking
 check = []

```
for k,v in tot.items():
    check.append(k)
    for j,l in v.items():
        check.append(l)
```

FYI ,  I am developing this solution to auto generate the cron schedules according to the user input

Comment: Do you just want to PRINT it like that?  Because that's not hard.

Comment: Please post the code that shows what you've tried so we can improve on your solution